# Print to a network printer using swift without airprint

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I'm trying to print to a label printer from a swift based application. I tried airprint label printers like "Leitz icon" or "Brother QL-710W", but both cut after every label (that's a problem for me). Printing to these printers with airprint worked tho. But because of the cutting, I try to print to a non-airprint label printer (Zebra GK420d right now).

I don't want to use a computer that enables airprint on that printer (with applications like "Printopia"), because I'd need an additional device.

Can someone help me to print to a network label printer without using airprint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to open a direct TCP socket connection to the printer and send the required data.

Comment: any tips on how to print an image over tcp? (In the end, I need a barcode printed with some additional text-based informations. I suppose it's the easiest way to convert these informations into an image first, isn't it?)

Comment: You will need to refer to documentation for the printer. I don't know this model but knowing Zebra printers in general I am sure there will be a command you can send to get it to print a barcode. See https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: you need to send ZPL commands to the printer